# C# XML Parsing guidance

Tags: xml-parsing

**[UPDATED]**I have a very complex XML that I used to parse using PowerBuilder and PBDOM.

I need to write a parser using C# as a windows service.

I have read lots of tutorials but they were based on very simple examples with XMLs of one or two levels depth.

I need your help about the methodology. I put here a very small **sample**. This is part of a quite huge XML schema but if I understand how to work this in .NET I can cope with the rest.

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <OTA_ResRetrieveRS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" EchoToken="echo" TimeStamp="2013-11-11T16:50:20.476" Version="1.0">
        <Success/>
        <ReservationsList>
            <HotelReservation CreateDateTime="2013-11-08T20:17:52" ResStatus="Book">
                <UniqueID ID="O0" Type="414"/>
                <POS>
                    <Source>
                        <RequestorID ID="SX" Type="212"/>
```

My code

```
XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

    mgr.AddNamespace("df", "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05");

    XmlNodeList ReservationsListList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ReservationsList");

    for (int a = 0; a < ReservationsListList.Count; a++)
    {
        XmlNodeList HotelReservationList = ReservationsListList[a].SelectNodes("//df:HotelReservation",mgr);


        for (int b = 0; b < HotelReservationList.Count; b++)
        {

            XmlNodeList UniqueIDList = HotelReservationList[b].SelectNodes("/df:UniqueID", mgr);

            for (int c = 0; c < UniqueIDList.Count; c++)
            {
                string UniqueIDID = UniqueIDList[c].Attributes.GetNamedItem("ID").Value;
                string UniqueIDType = UniqueIDList[c].Attributes.GetNamedItem("Type").Value;
            }

            XmlNodeList UniqueIDList2 = HotelReservationList[b].SelectNodes("/df:POS", mgr);
            for (int c = 0; c < UniqueIDList2.Count; c++)
            {
                XmlNodeList SourceList = UniqueIDList2[c].SelectNodes("/df:Source", mgr);

                for (int d = 0; d < SourceList.Count; d++)
                {
                    XmlNodeList RequestorIDList = SourceList[d].SelectNodes("/RequestorID");

                    for (int f = 0; f < RequestorIDList.Count; f++)
                    {
                        string RequestorIDID = RequestorIDList[f].Attributes.GetNamedItem("ID").Value;
                        string RequestorIDType = RequestorIDList[f].Attributes.GetNamedItem("Type").Value;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }



    }
```

Lets suppose that there are **20 HotelReservation** elements in the XML. Each one has one **ID** and one **Type** inside the **UniqueID** element.

When I loop inside **UniqueID** for the **first HotelReservation**, it loops **20 times** giving me all the **ID** and **Type** of the XML!

I replaced // with / and I get empty!

Can u help me spot the mistake?

Thanx in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far? Parsing and handling a deep XML document is not very different from  handling a shallower one; you just need to walk deeper into the tree (for a parser that builds a DOM) or that maintains a bit more context (for a parser that generates SAX events).

Comment: I can load the XML but I have problems how to go to the children and the children's children

Comment: OK, what have you tried, and what happened?

Comment: If I can read some code that goes two levels in, I can take it from there

Comment: XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("Rates");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
        {
            

            XmlNodeList xnList = elemList[i].SelectNodes("//Rate");


            foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
            {
                textBox1.Text = (xn.InnerXml);
            }

            
        }  
    

        }

Comment: OK, that's using XPath. If that's the approach you want, change the SelectNodes to a path that finds the value you're looking for, eg "//GuestCount" or "//Comment/Text" See an XPath tutorial for more information about how to express these searches.

Comment: Code added, question updated